# What are some other gases that liquify at around the same temperature as ammonia?

Tags: liquids

I am looking for gases that have a liquefication that falls within or on the edges of the liquefication range of Ammonia. I am mainly looking for gases that are comprised mainly of Carbon, Nitrogen, Oxygen, Hydrogen, Chlorine and Fluorine and liquify in a similar temperature and pressure range. This is for a worldbuilding project, but since the question is real, not theoretical, chemistry, I thought it would be better to ask about it here.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has a large list of gasses in ambient conditions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_gases) as well as a list of refrigerants [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_refrigerants). You can sort them in order of boiling point by clicking on the small black triangles just underneath the respective column. Then just look for things in the range of ammonia, which boils at -33 °C under 1 bar. Note that a large number of entries in the table for refrigerants are for mixtures of gasses.

I don't think these lists are complete, but there are comparatively few substances with such low boiling points (probably no more than a few thousand that could ever be made), simply because having more than a handful of atoms will already cause the molecules to attract enough to remain as liquids or solids at non-cryogenic temperatures.

Answer (score 1):

I found few gasses under the category of the gases, which have a boiling points (at atmospheric pressure) that falls within the boiling point of Ammonia. since you are mainly looking for gases that are comprised mainly of Carbon, Nitrogen, Oxygen, Hydrogen, Chlorine, and Fluorine, these gases are ideal for your purpose:

$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
\text{Name of the compound (gas)} & \text{Boiling point at } \pu{760 mmHg} \\
\hline
\text{Ammonia, } \ce{NH3} & \pu{-35.5 ^\circ C} \\
\text{Chloromethane (Metyl Chloride), } \ce{CH3Cl} & \pu{-23.9 ^\circ C} \\
\text{1,1-Difluoroethane (Freon refrigerant R-152a), } \ce{CHF2CH3} & \pu{-25 ^\circ C} \\
\text{Methoxymethane (Methyl Ether), } \ce{CH3OCH3} & \pu{-25 ^\circ C} \\
\text{1,1,1,2-Tetrafluoroethane (Freon refrigerant R-134a), } \ce{CF3CH2F} & \pu{-26.3 ^\circ C} \\
\text{Dichlorodifluoromethane (Freon refrigerant R-12), } \ce{CCl2F2} & \pu{-29.8 ^\circ C} \\
\color{Red} {\text{Chlorine, } \ce{Cl2}} & \color{Red} {\pu{-34.4 ^\circ C}}\\
\text{Octafluoropropane (Freon refrigerant R-218), } \ce{CF3CF2CF3} & \pu{-36.7 ^\circ C} \\
\text{Chloropentafluoroethane (Freon refrigerant R-115), } \ce{CClF2CF3} & \pu{-39.1 ^\circ C} \\
\text{Chlorodifluoromethane (Freon refrigerant R-22), } \ce{CHClF2} & \pu{-41.2 ^\circ C} \\
\text{Propane, } \ce{CH3CH2CH3} & \pu{-42 ^\circ C} \\
\text{Propyne, } \ce{CH#CCH3} & \pu{-47.7 ^\circ C} \\
\text{Propene, } \ce{CH2=CHCH3} & \pu{-47.72 ^\circ C} \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Among these gases, chlorine has come the most closest to ammonia.

[Most data are from this source](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/boiling-points-fluids-gases-d_155.html) and [most Freon data are from this source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_refrigerants).